# Eventbrite API : each event seems to have a unique venue id value, even though the venue is the same in theory

Tags: eventbrite

I need to obtain a list of all the events happening at a single venue.   I know it's not possible to search events directly anymore in the API but another strategy is to get the venue id from an event and then in a second query get all the events from that venue id, using this endpoint: [https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/venues/**[venue_id]**/events/](https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/venues/**%5Bvenue_id%5D**/events/)

The issue I have is that with the 3 current live events at the venue I need to work with, all 3 of them have unique venue ID's.  I was imagining that the same venue ID would be returned for all of them but that isn't the case.

How is this possible, does the API always work like this?  I'd assumed every location that the platform has ever listed an event for would have a single entry in their venues database.